# How to get Linq data context for this function?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework 6.0 in a class library project and I'm trying to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197054/assigning-linq-result-to-datatable) solution in my project to convert LINQ results to Datatable.

```
public DataTable ToDataTable(System.Data.Linq.DataContext ctx, object query)
{
     if (query == null)
     {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
     }

     IDbCommand cmd = ctx.GetCommand(query as IQueryable);
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
     adapter.SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)cmd;
     DataTable dt = new DataTable("sd");

     try
     {
          cmd.Connection.Open();
          adapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source); 
          adapter.Fill(dt);
     }
     finally
     {
          cmd.Connection.Close();
     }
     return dt;
}
```

However, i'm not quite sure what Linq DataContext is and how I can send it to this function. Any help please?

Comment: `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` is the LinqtoSql data context, it has nothing to do with Entity Framework, i.e. you haven't got one and you can't pass it to the method. You would have to follow the first example in the linked question that just uses reflection to turn an `IEnumerable<T>` into a `DataTable`.  I do wonder why you would want to do this though.

Comment: @BenRobinson, I need to bind my linq results to gridview, but since the selected columns in linq doesn't map to a specific entity so I can't convert the linq result to , for example, '.ToList<Person>'. So I thought of converting it to datatable. Any advice on that?

Comment: You don't have any LIMNQ results.  You are simply extract data from a SQL Server to a datatable.  You want to bind the datatable to a gridview.  See webpage : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15070/GridView-to-a-DataTable

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind a list of entities to a gridview. This is usually the right way to work.
Otherwise you can use the query generated by EF and then populate the datatable with.

```
public DataTable ToDataTable(DbConnection connection, IQueryable query)
{
     if (connection == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");

     if (query == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("query");

     string sqlQuery = query.ToString();

     DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
     DbDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
     adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
     DataTable dt = new DataTable("sd");

     try
     {
          cmd.Connection.Open();
          adapter.Fill(dt);
     }
     finally
     {
          cmd.Connection.Close();
     }
     return dt;
}
```

Example of use

```
BloggingContext context = new BloggingContext(connection);
var query = context.Blogs.Where(b => b.BlogId == 25);
DataTable dataTable = ToDataTable(context.Database.Connection, query);
```